# List of psychological conditions, disorders and illnesses

Tags: diagnosis, publication, disorder

I would be grateful to anyone who takes some time to answer. Is there any up-to-date list of all psychological conditions, disorders and illnesses, in the strict neuro-psychiatric scientific definition?

Would a list of such conditions, disorders and illnesses be different under the context of contemporary psychoanalysis (not of-course pure Freud based from the 1900s)? Or would they be included in the above-mentioned list? If not, is there the second list, *psychoanalytical oriented*, but still based on scientific publications?

Any form of such a list (or catalog), including *wikipedia, medpud or other major Journal publication or even a scientific book*, would work.

Thanks and please do understand the "anonymous" posting

Answer (score 3):

The [DSM-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSM-5) is the current version of the diagnostic manual of the APA.

It's hard to say there is any such thing as a "strict neuro-psychiatric" definition; these definitions are by their nature not strict at all, but the DSM is probably the closest thing to some level of unified understanding in the field. That doesn't mean everyone agrees with it - they certainly don't - and you can infer from changes from edition to edition that it is all far from settled.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the DSM-5, the World Health Organisation maintains the International Classification of Diseases, currently on it's 11th revision ([ICD-11](https://icd.who.int/en)). It contains far more than just psychological disorders, but these are included.